# printing Dictionary using "for" loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

states = {
'Orengon': 'OR'
'Florida': 'FL'
'California': 'CA'
'New York': 'NY'
'Michigan': 'MI'
}

for state, abbrev in list(states.items()):

```
   print(f"{state} is abbreviated {abbrev}")
```

Here in "for" loop why are we using "list" keyword?

and what is .items keyword for(states.items)?

Comment: `list` in unrequired - so I would remove it. `items()` returns tuples of the key and value of the dictionary. If you didn't have items, then you would be only getting the keys of the dictionary (which would then fail as python won't know how to fill out the 2 variables)

Comment: Please add your code as text, not as an image!

Comment: Sure sir.......

Answer (score 1):

```
list(states.items())
```

It will convert it into list. However, it is not needed as states.items() returns list on tuples.

**Dictionary**

```
states = { 'Orengon': 'OR', 'Florida': 'FL', 'California': 'CA', 'New York': 'NY', 'Michigan': 'MI', }
```

**After performing states.items()**

```
[('Orengon', 'OR'), ('Michigan', 'MI'), ('New York', 'NY'), ('Florida', 'FL'), ('California', 'CA')]
```

**After performing list(states.items())**

```
[('Orengon', 'OR'), ('Michigan', 'MI'), ('New York', 'NY'), ('Florida', 'FL'), ('California', 'CA')]
```

Comment: Thank you Sir for your answer

Comment: Hello Mahesh Sir... sir actually stack flow is not allowing me to ask another question... so can I ask you another question here in comment box...?

Comment: @SkNurulIslam Hello and thanks but dont call me sir my friend ! we can chat community chat if you face any other issue. Feel free to ping!